# Будут ли на ruSO коллективы?

Tags: обсуждение, коллективы

Обнаружил (причем где-то с месяц как) на enSO коллективы - https://stackoverflow.com/collectives. Будет ли у нас (на ruSO) что-то подобное, что для этого нужно и есть ли интерес в этом у участников сообщества? Я понимаю, что вопросов мало, людей мало, бла-бла-бла, но все же интересно.

Comment: Например, по каким конкретно тематикам вам бы хотелось собрать коллективы?

Comment: ... ‍♀️Microsoft Azure

Comment: Коллективы - это по сути, реклама конкретной компании/конкретного продукта. Они добавляются в список только после того, как компания [подаст заявление](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416874/6808809), и обговорит все детали, выделит ответственного сотрудника, и так далее. Другими словами, есть компании - есть и коллективы. Я думаю, вы понимаете, что на RU сейчас нет официальных представителей компаний, да и сама SO не особо вкладывается в наше развитие (яб сказал даже наоборот, забирает). Так о каких коллективах может идти речь?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ при чем тут компании? https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php где тут компании?

Comment: @aepot да по тому же php, а если не удастся привлечь компании (типа Яндекс для их карт, API и прочего), по факту будет мертвое комьюнити?

Comment: @DaemonHK Что значит при чем, прочитайте ответ по ссылке, там все написано. У PHP также есть компания-разработчик, PHP Group.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight то есть на локальные рынки тот же PHP не сможет выйти... Ну да, такое. А было прикольно выделить топовые вопросы/ответы как у них там сделано. Жаль...

Comment: @DaemonHK Если зайдете в раздел "Members" и посмотрите кто ответственен за коллектив (админы), то увидите там сотрудников SO. Ну а если проделаете тоже самое, например, у Microsoft, то увидите там даже новые аккаунты с рейтингом 1, и припиской `Microsoft Azure Employee` (сотрудник Microsoft). Это я к тому, что всякие PHP,R,CI/CD были созданы с самого старта, скорей всего как некий образец, ну а все остальные - имеют конкретное представительство, конкретной компании. В любом случае, это не отменяет тот факт, что заявка подается **только** от лица конкретной компании, а не простого смертного.

Comment: Мм, я упустил тот факт, что коллективы оказывается еще и [платные](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411792/6808809). Короче, чисто корпоративный сегмент, ни единого шанса для простых смертных увидеть что-то подобное.

Comment: А зачем вам как юзеру коллективы?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat узел, в котором собраны интересные вопросы?

Comment: Я точно не смотрел, но разве туда не попадает все подряд с определенным тегом? Можно просто искать по тегу.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну такое, если честно. Тут все говорят, не ходите на главную, пользуйтесь тегами, но хочется удобства какого-то, хз))

Comment: А чем плоха главная? У меня на главной справа висит панель "пользовательские фильтры", где точками отмечены теги (точнее фильтры) с новыми вопросами.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat старыми вопросами, которые бот поднимает или рейтингодро...

Comment: А коллективы их не показывают? Ну и порядок - это часть фильтра, настраиваете один раз "по новизне" и счастье.

Answer (score 8):

Скорее нет, чем да.

1. Компания не заинтересована в добавлении нового функционала на ruSO.
2. Участников всё-таки не так много, так что сложно организовать популярный коллектив.

Можно, конечно, попытаться сделать такой коллектив "вручную" - создать чатик, кидать ссылки на интересные вопросы/ответы, определять лучших участников... Не факт, что это будет пользоваться популярностью - в чаты вообще мало кто заглядывает. Но попробовать можно. Вот только будет ли кто-нибудь это организовывать...

#### Список попыток создать коллектив вручную:

- [Дискуссии о C#/.NET на русском](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--) - раньше активность была, но в последний раз туда писали 511 дней назад...
- [Чат С/С++](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26298/c-c) - активности очень мало, но время от времени там кто-то есть, и это хорошо. В тот чатик ещё feeds прикрутили, чтобы чат не заморозился и не потерялся. Это хорошее решение.
- [Svg_chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat) - нет активности с весны, но недавно разморозили. feeds туда ничего не пишет. Поэтому чат замораживается, его в списке чатов нет, в результате чат мёртв.
- [java](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147671/java) - моя собственная попытка создать что-то вроде коллектива. Его я только-только создал, будет ли туда кто-то заглядывать - вопрос. Пока делаю вот что: кидаю ссылки на незамеченные, неоценённые вопросы и ответы, нахожу лучшие вопросы и ответы за день. Планирую развивать этот чат.

Comment: Один такой уже есть - [Svg_chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat), но и он уже почти заброшен.

Comment: feeds **не может** удерживать комнату от заморозки.

Comment: Чтобы комната не замораживалась, нужно чтобы реальные аккаунты писали туда, а не Feeds.

Comment: @Petəíŕd-CSC вы уверены?

Comment: @Зонтик да, я уверен.